# Classic ASP / Printing results horizontally (8 rows, x columns)

Tags: css, asp-classic

Can anybody help or point me in the right direction for a tutorial/example for printing recordsets horizontally, with fixed rows and variable columns. The desired effect:

```
A------  Crime     Estimate
Air      Curtains  Estoria
Alpha    D------   F------
Apple    Daily     ...
B------  Doctor    ...
Banana   E------
Billy    Eddie
C------  Elephant
Chair    Eskimo

[<]-------[|||||||]-------------------------------[>]
```

I have a DIV with horizontal scroll (like my imitation scrollbar above lol) and need to scroll along the alphabetical list of words. I need to have 8 rows high and that should include the new character heading (A, B, C...) but the amount of columns, nobody knows.

Maybe there's an easier way using CSS. If each word was a block of 100x20px, the first block would have `top:0px; left:0px;`, the next block would have `top:20px; left:0px;` and then on the next column, `top:0px; left:100px;`...

I could probably do it if somebody explained how. Any help or tutorial links gratefully received as always.

**MY RESULT**

Made with CSS positioning instead of table rows/cells. Happy!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to weave it into an HTML table where <tr> is a table row and <td> is a table cell or column.

This example shows a standard recordset to table but you will need to change the code to meet your desired format.

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?lngWId=4&txtCodeId=7466

Comment: Thanks @Dee. I am capable of coding a standard recordset table, without looking at a tutorial, just not in the format I need. I'm going to have a bash using CSS positioning instead of table..

Comment: It's the same thing, Create a table, create a column - loop thru the records creating rows, test for boundary condition, if found close column start a new column, and repeat.  at end of records close table.

Comment: Thanks for your input, much appreciated. I originally wanted a table method but because of my hate for tables, I had a go with CSS positioning instead, and got the same result and probably saved a few lines of code too. I just couldn't work out how to print the table in that way. Anyway, thanks.